# Voids blueshifting CMB photons (in certain cases)?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, astrophysics, cosmic-microwave-background, structure-formation

I have some questions about this interesting work (https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/517603/pdf) where the authors analysed the effects of voids in the CMB radiation (particularly through the Integrated Sachs-Wolfe and the Rees-Sciama effect).

This effect predicts that photons crossing overdensities would be blueshifted and the ones crossing voids would be redshifted. However, in this paper it is indicated that there can be a cancellation of the redshift of photons crossing the voids. In particular, I quote the following from the article:

> As shown in Figure 2, an increase in $\epsilon$ leads to further redshifts of the photons due to reduction in the expansion rate inside the void. Therefore, for voids that expand with the asymptotic velocity, the second-order effect always enhances the linear ISW effect. On the contrary, for $\epsilon < 0$ , the second-order effect leads to further blue- shifts of the photons. Therefore, for voids that expand sufficiently faster than the asymptotic velocity of the wall(i.e., $\delta H > \beta$),the second-order effect can reduce the redshift of photons due to the linear ISW effect. Furthermore, an increase in the velocity of the wall (i.e., $\eta >0$) also leads to a suppression of the linear ISW effect, because the photon is more Doppler blueshifted (see Fig. 2, right). Thus, the net redshift / blueshift of photons upon leaving the void depends on whether it is asymptotically evolving or not.

So this seems to indicate that there are cases where even photons crossing a void can be blueshifted when getting out of it. So my question is:

Is this correct? Can there be cases where the photons crossing the voids have a total net blueshift as they get out of them?

PS: I'm aware that photons would still have a redshift from the overall expansion of the universe, but I'm asking my questions putting that aside for a moment.